# Cannot Resolve Method although method is inside my class

Tags: android

I made a method called "fetch" inside my code as you can see and when I try to call it inside the "onRefresh" method Android Studio tells me cannot resolve the method 'fetch'.

Here is the code I have provided if you look inside the `onRefresh` method and the `fetch` method you can take a look.

```
package com.petersoboyejo.csgoesportsscores;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static MainActivity instance = null;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
    private ListView drawerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance = this;

        setTitle("Matches");

        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar,
                R.string.open, R.string.close
        );
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.app_sections)));
        // drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ImagesFragment())
                    .commit();
        }



        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                fetch();

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class ImagesFragment extends Fragment {

        private ImageRecordsAdapter mAdapter;

        public ImagesFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_images, container, false);
        }



        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            mAdapter = new ImageRecordsAdapter(getActivity());

            ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list1);
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



            fetch();
        }


        private void fetch() {
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    ("https://api.import.io/store/data/2ac9dccd-71de-4aff-9efb-6643ac8bcc58/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hltv.org%2F%3Fpageid%3D188%26gameid%3D2&_user=65a387f2-10ed-413f-b4fc-b8f012d4c6ca&_apikey=65a387f2-10ed-413f-b4fc-b8f012d4c6ca%3A94W7S%2F461ByRd5Cr3dpu8F3djWvx%2Frk%2FKWKWnAfSxdp%2BWhWJmh0VCK8sZoBi4vnyXLgxIGaEQ%2BO2Vk4IqEs%2FYg%3D%3D"),
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                            try {
                                List<ImageRecord> imageRecords = parse(jsonObject);


                                mAdapter.swapImageRecords(imageRecords);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to parse data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            VolleyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);

        }



        private List<ImageRecord> parse(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
            ArrayList<ImageRecord> records = new ArrayList<ImageRecord>();

            JSONArray jsonImages = json.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonImages.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonImage = jsonImages.getJSONObject(i);

                String teamoneflag = jsonImage.getString("teamoneflag");
                String teamtwoflag = jsonImage.getString("teamtwoflag");

                String teamone = jsonImage.getString("teamone");
                String teamtwo = jsonImage.getString("teamtwo");
                String event = jsonImage.getString("event");
                String dateplayed = jsonImage.getString("dateplayed");
                String map = jsonImage.getString("map");

                ImageRecord record = new ImageRecord(teamoneflag, teamtwoflag, teamone, teamtwo, event, dateplayed, map);
                records.add(record);
            }

            return records;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you set the method private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this inside `onRefresh()`:

```
((ImagesFragment) MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container)).fetch();
```

Explain:

- `MainActivity.this`: you have to reach the `MainActivity` in that way, because `onRefresh()` in an anonymous class.
- `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container))`: It finds the previously added `ImagesFragment`.

Comment: Wow! Thank's for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the fetch method is inside the inner class `ImagesFragment` and it is `private`. To use it in `onRefresh()` make it public static like `public static fetch(){}` and call it like this `ImagesFragment.fetch()`

Comment: Thank's for helping me out means a lot especially since I learned something new :)